# Returing method for string

Tags: java, string

Hei guys, so i got this code:

```
String arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
String wow64Arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");
String realArch = arch.endsWith("64")
    || wow64Arch != null && wow64Arch.endsWith("64")
       ? "64" : "32";

public String officeLoc() throws IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException{
if(realArch.contains("64")){
    String tempLoc = WinRegistry.readString (
        WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                     //HKEY
        "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsfot\\Office",         //Key
        "InstallDir");                                      //ValueName
    System.out.println("Location = " + tempLoc);
    }else{
    String tempLoc = WinRegistry.readString (
        WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                     //HKEY
        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\",                    //Key
        "InstallDir");                                      //ValueName
    System.out.println("Location = " + tempLoc);
    }
}
```

And i can't return the tempLoc value to officeLoc. I tried with return string x; or even static but it doesn't work like that.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to improve your code, but focusing on the problem at hand: Your confusion probably centers around the [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) of `tempLoc`. If you have something like this:

```
public String officeLoc () {
    if (...) {
        String tempLoc = ...;
    } else {
        String tempLoc = ...;
    }
}
```

Then the scope of those *two different* `tempLoc` variables is only between the `{` and `}` around them; `tempLoc` isn't visible any more once it goes out of scope. You wouldn't, therefore, be able to do this (which it sounds like you tried):

```
public String officeLoc () {
    if (...) {
        String tempLoc = ...;
    } else {
        String tempLoc = ...;
    }
    return tempLoc; // <- can't do this, tempLoc is out of scope
}
```

You have two options, basically. You could either do this:

```
public String officeLoc () {
    if (...) {
        String tempLoc = ...;
        return tempLoc; // <- no problem
    } else {
        String tempLoc = ...;
        return tempLoc; // <- no problem
    }
}
```

Or you could move `tempLoc` up to a higher scope, like this:

```
public String officeLoc () {
    String tempLoc; // <- declare it here
    if (...) {
        tempLoc = ...; // <- set its value
    } else {
        tempLoc = ...; // <- set its value
    }
    return tempLoc; // <- no problem
}
```

Either way it needs to be visible in the scope that the `return` statement is in. Personally, I prefer the latter, as I like to minimize return points as a style choice, but that's up to you.

You may also wish to read a bit about [`static`](http://crunchify.com/java-static-methods-variables-static-block-and-class-with-example/), as your attempt to use it suggests that you may not fully understand what it's actually for.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you study the rules for java syntax. Because: unless you have typos in your code example, your problem is simply that your method

```
public String officeLoc() ...
```

is missing a final

```
  return tempLoc;
}
```

statement! (well, but as Jason mentions in his answer: that would only work if you declared tempLoc exactly once in the beginning of that method.

And just for the sake of it, you would rewrite the whole thing

```
public String officeLoc() throws IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException{
  if(realArch.contains("64")) {
    return lookupRegistry("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsfot\\Office");
  }

  return lookupRegistry("SOFTWARE\\Microsfot\\Office");                                       
}
```

and have a helper method lookupRegistry(String key) that does

```
return WinRegistry.readString (
    WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, "InstallDir");
```

You see: you absolutely want to minimize the amount of code duplication!

Comment: Great advice, although it's more than just the missing final return. Just adding that as-is to the end of the function wouldn't get it to compile (I imagine the OP already tried that) since `tempLoc` is declared inside the `if` blocks. It sounds like the real problem is the OP didn't understand the scope of `tempLoc` then made a few hand-waving attempts but failed.

Comment: @JasonC Sure, you already got your +1; as i think your answer is great too. I overlooked the scope thingy.

Answer (score 0):

So i did some rethinking and i came up with this:

```
String setWin = ((realArch.contains("64")) ? "SOFTWARE\\Wow64Node\\Microsoft\\Office" : "SFOTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office");

String officeLoc = WinRegistry.readString(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,setWin,"InstallDir");
```

But the officeLoc string has an unreported exception "IllegalAccessException" and I'm not sure how to caught or thrown it //or which way is better

PS: Thanks for advice Jason C i totally forgot about static